# winforms - how do I setup Checkbox's in a Groupbox so that I can reference checkbox states at the group level?

Tags: winforms, checkbox, groupbox

I am working on a WinForms app in C#, VS2008.

How do I setup Checkbox's in a Groupbox so that I can reference checkbox states at the group level?   For example 7 checkboxes for each day of the week.  Then I would like to be able get the state when checking via something like:  "result = daysOfWeek.Monday;"

I'm probably missing the obvious somewhere...

thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CheckedListBox` and change the background, border, and selection properties.